# \n characters before EOF in file causing problems

Tags: c, newline, eof

I have written some data to a file manually i.e. not by my application.

My code is reading the data char by char and storing them in different arrays but my program gets stuck when I insert the condition EOF.

After some investigation I found out that in my file before EOF there are three to four `\n` characters. I have not inserted them. I don't understand why they are in my file.

Comment: What editor are you using for editing data? If you need this level of control - like no ending \n characters - it's a good idea to use a hex editor (e.g. bvi), not a normal text editor.

Comment: You are missing a `;` in line 42 of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Want to remove those pesky extra characters?  First, see how many of them there are at the end of your file:

```
od -c <filename> | tail
```

Then, remove however many characters you don't like.  If it's 3:

```
truncate -s -3 <filename>
```

But overall, if it were me, I'd change my program to discard undesired newline characters, unless they're truly invalid according to the input file format specification.

Comment: sir is there a way to remove these character using c programming

Comment: Sure, just read the file one character at a time until you find the character you don't like, then call the C function `ftruncate()` on the file descriptor passing the number of bytes you read that you did like.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is very easy to add additional newlines to the end of a file in every text editor. You have to push the cursor around to see them. Open your file in your editor and see what happens when you navigate to the end, you'll see the extra newlines.
2. There is no such thing as an EOF character in general. Windows treats control-Z as EOF in some cases. Perhaps you are talking about the return value from some API that indicates that it has reached the end of file?

Comment: thank u sir but is there a through which i can remove them using c language